# Javascript Angular 4 Change ngClass from another Component

Tags: javascript, angular

I currently have this code in my app.component.ts

app.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="myclass">
    ...rest of the content here
</div>
```

This I have the this:

```
<button (click)="changeClass('myFavClass')">Change Class to myFavClass</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  myclass: string;

  changeClass(myclass) {
    this.myclass = myclass;
  }

}
```

Now, all this works fine BUT I now want to put the triggering button on another component.

If I put this on another component:

```
<button (click)="changeClass('myFavClass')">Change Class to myFavClass</div>
```

How can I get it to change the class?

Comment: What "another component". Please provide the code (TS+HTML) that demonstrates how the components are related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a value in two different components at the same time Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771511/changing-a-value-in-two-different-components-at-the-same-time-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options. `Subject and Observable` or if this `another` component is a parent you can use `@Input`.

`Subject and Observable` method:

[angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) Highly recommended to read whole page.

**Some component**

```
export class SomeComponent {
   constructor(private ClassService: ClassService) {  }
   private changeClass(class) {
      this.ClassService.changeClass(class);
   }
}
```

**Another Component**

```
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   constructor(private ClassService: ClassService) {  }
   private class: string = "";
   private subscribtion: Subscribtion;
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.Subscribtion = this.ClassService.someClass$.subscribe(
         (class) => { this.class = class; }
      )
   }
   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.Subscribtion.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable();
export class ClassService{
   constructor() {  }

   private someClassSource= new Subject<string>();

   someClass$= this.someClassSource.asObservable();

   changeClass(class) {
      this.someClassSource.next(class);
   }
}
```

taken from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124292/angular2-way-to-update-data-in-nested-component-from-parent-component/43889482#43889482)

`@Input` method:

[angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

This is very simple, when you click button `changeClass` method will change `elClass` which will be passed to `another component` by `@Input` decorator, every change of `@Input` will cause a detect changes which will detect that value has changed so class will change to `myClass`.

**Parent component**

```
parent.component.html
<another-component [elementClass]="elClass"></another-component>
<button (click)="changeClass('myClass')">change class<button>

parent.component.ts
export class ParentComponnet {
   private elClass: string = "";
   changeClass(class: string) {
      elClass = class;
   }
}
```

**Another component (must be child component)**

```
another.component.html
<div [ngClass]="elementClass">

another.component.ts
export class AnotherComponent {
   @Input() elementClass: string;
}
```

There is also Child to Parent interaction via `@Output` (emitting event) [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this you can use [output with an EventEmit](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Or you can set up a service that monitors the changes to a variable and use that as the control point for the change.

Personally, I use services for this instance as its easier to manage the code and its flow.

This answer has all the code in you need to look at.

[Changing a value in two different components at the same time Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771511/changing-a-value-in-two-different-components-at-the-same-time-angular-2/41771878#41771878)

Hope that helps